# SQL UPDATE with CASE, GROUP BY, and HAVING

Tags: sql, sql-server

The SELECT statement below returns the correct data.

```
SELECT stu.sc, stu.sn, COUNT(*) AS Total,
    CASE
      WHEN COUNT(*) = 3 Then 'Letter 1'
      WHEN COUNT(*) = 4 Then 'Letter 2'
      WHEN COUNT(*) = 5 Then 'Letter 3'
      ELSE 'SARB'
    END AS Letter  
FROM STU  join att ON (stu.SC = att.SC and stu.SN = att.SN)
WHERE att.al in ('c','t','u')
GROUP by stu.sc, stu.sn
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

I need to perform an UPDATE based on that query, and I can't seem to figure it out.  I've looked at multiple examples online that are similar to what I need, but I can't get this to work.  I need to be able to do something like this...

```
UPDATE stu
SET stu.tru = 
   CASE
     When COUNT(*) = 3 Then 'Letter 1'
     When COUNT(*) = 4 Then 'Letter 2'
     When COUNT(*) = 5 Then 'Letter 3'
     ELSE 'SARB'
   END  
FROM stu  JOIN att
   on (stu.sc = att.sc and stu.sn = att.sn)
WHERE ATT.AL in ('c','t','u')
GROUP BY stu.sc, stu.sn
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

I know I can't use Group By and Having in an Update statement directly, but I've seen examples where they use a Select with Group By before the Set and Join.  I just can't make it work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?  2000? 2005? 2008?

Comment: I see your response below, but I'll update this anyway.  I'm using SQL Server 2008.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT stu.sc, stu.sn, COUNT(*) AS Total,
      CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) = 3 Then 'Letter 1'
        WHEN COUNT(*) = 4 Then 'Letter 2'
        WHEN COUNT(*) = 5 Then 'Letter 3'
        ELSE 'SARB'
      END AS Letter  
  FROM STU  join att ON (stu.SC = att.SC and stu.SN = att.SN)
  WHERE att.al in ('c','t','u')
  GROUP by stu.sc, stu.sn
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
)
UPDATE stu
SET stu.tru = cte.Letter
FROM stu  JOIN cte
   on (stu.sc = cte.sc and stu.sn = cte.sn)
```

Comment: I decided to test this tonight and it works perfectly.  In your opinion, is there a more 'proper' way to achieve this when comparing this solution to Michael's below?  I don't know who to give the 'Accepted' answer too, as they both work. -- Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE stu
SET tru = sub.letter
FROM
    stu JOIN (
    SELECT stu.sc, stu.sn,
        CASE
          WHEN COUNT(*) = 3 THEN 'Letter 1'
          WHEN COUNT(*) = 4 THEN 'Letter 2'
          WHEN COUNT(*) = 5 THEN 'Letter 3'
          ELSE 'SARB'
        END AS Letter  
    FROM STU 
    JOIN att ON (stu.SC = att.SC AND stu.SN = att.SN)
    WHERE att.al in ('c','t','u')
    GROUP by stu.sc, stu.sn
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
) sub ON stu.sc = sub.sc AND stu.sn = sub.sn
```

Comment: I decided to test this tonight and it works perfectly.  In your opinion, is there a more 'proper' way to achieve this when comparing this solution to Malk's above?  I don't know who to give the 'Accepted' answer too, as they both work.  --  Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @AnthonyGattuso I believe they are functionally equivalent; the difference being the sub-select vs the CTE.  CTEs are usually preferred over sub-selects, however, they aren't available in Sql Server 2000 or earlier.  I wasn't sure what version of Sql you were using, so I didn't use a CTE... but since you're using Sql 2008 which supports CTEs, I would go with Malk's answer.