# Update only if Existing value is less than new value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make this code update the existing [Price] ONLY when the i.[Price] is greater than the existing. I would appreciate your help.

MyDatabase        set ANSI_NULLS ON
        set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO
--This trigger is attached to the Price_Import Table so when this table gets new price values the trigger will update the price of such items in the Mydatabase MenuItem Table which is the main item table in Mydatabase

```
     ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgafterinsertinto_Price_Import_Table] ON [dbo].[Price_Import]
AFTER INSERT
    AS 
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

     UPDATE [dbo].[MenuItem] 
SET [Price] = i.[Price] ,[Cost] = i.[Cost]
    FROM Inserted i
   WHERE MenuItem.PLU = i.PLU
   DELETE FROM dbo.Price_Import
   END
```

This code update both Cost and Price but I need help modifying it to only update price when the new price is greater than the old.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean you want to update the *row* only when the condition is met, just add in that condition, either in the `on` clause or `where` clause:

```
UPDATE mi
    SET Price = i.Price,
        Cost = i.Cost
    FROM [dbo].[MenuItem] mi JOIN
         Inserted i
         on mi.PLU = i.PLU AND i.Price > mi.Price;
```

If you really mean `price` only, then use `case` instead:

```
UPDATE mi
    SET Price = (CASE WHEN i.Price > mi.Price THEN i.Price ELSE mi.Price END)
        Cost = i.Cost
    FROM [dbo].[MenuItem] mi JOIN
         Inserted i
         on mi.PLU = i.PLU;
```

Answer (score 0):

you might need something like this [stackUpdateHaving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962347/sql-update-with-case-group-by-and-having)

just put a having clause into your where clause like : HAVING m.val > m.incVal